# Position of "with the same name" in sentence

Tags: sentence-structure, word-order

I wrote:

> Unlike global variables, if there is already a local variable in the list, with the same name <strike>of</strike> as a new variable, the old variable isn’t replaced.

I thought maybe the distance between "with the same name..." is long. So, I wrote:

> Unlike global variables, if a local variable with the same name <strike>of</strike> as a new variable already exists in the list, the old variable isn’t replaced.

Are both sentences equivalent? Which is more fluent?

Comment: A note on the phrase "same name of" -- **as** is a more idiomatic preposition than **of** here.  "The same as" is a common phrase.  "I went to the same school as you," "She has the same name as her grandmother," "The weather is the same as it was last week."  You can compare [ngrams on "same name as" and "same name of."](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=same+name+of%2C+same+name+as&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csame%20name%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csame%20name%20as%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Actually, both of them read pretty well to me.  The second one is slightly clearer, I think, because "with the same name" is closer to the thing it applies to, as you point out.

Comment: "Unlike global variables, if a local variable *has* the **same name as** an *existing* variable, the *existing* variable isn’t replaced."  You need to be careful since even though the existing variable is not replaced, usually the *scope* of the **new** variable will effect how both get used.